# Plot of a changing matrix ... gone wrong

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix

I am trying to plot a matrix in Python. So, my initial thought was using matshow.

However, this particular matrix develop over time via an algorithm (the function sandpile below), so I need to show how the matrix develop over time - but in the same plot. The end result is sort of an animation. Any ideas as to how that is done ? The code below only produce one graph, and that is a picture of the very last updated matrix (matrix called abba, below).

Thank you in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dimension = 3
abba = np.matrix( [ [2,5,2], [1,1000,4], [2,1,2] ] )

def sandpile(field):

    greater3 = np.where(field > 3)
    
    left = (greater3[0], greater3[1]-1)
    right = (greater3[0], greater3[1]+1)
    top = (greater3[0] - 1, greater3[1])
    bottom = (greater3[0]+1 , greater3[1])

    bleft   = left[0][np.where(left[1] >= 0)], left[1][np.where(left[1] >= 0)]
    bright  = right[0][np.where(right[1] < dimension)], right[1][np.where(right[1] < dimension)]
    btop    = top[0][np.where(top[0] >= 0)], top[1][np.where(top[0] >= 0)]
    bbottom = bottom[0][np.where(bottom[0] < dimension)], bottom[1][np.where(bottom[0] < dimension)]

    field[greater3] -= 4

    field[bleft] += 1
    field[bright] += 1
    field[btop] += 1
    field[bbottom] += 1
            
    return (field) 

print(abba)

matfig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
plt.matshow(abba, fignum=matfig.number)

n = 0
while (abba < 4).all() == False:
    
    abba = sandpile(abba)
    
    plt.matshow(abba, fignum=matfig.number)
    
    n += 1

print('Exit with',n,'steps')
print(abba)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you can see an updating plot in a loop:

```
...

matfig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
ax1 = matfig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax_image = ax1.imshow(abba)
plt.show(block=False)

n = 0
while (abba < 4).all() == False:

    abba = sandpile(abba)

    ax_image.remove()
    ax_image = ax1.imshow(abba)
    matfig.canvas.draw()
    matfig.canvas.flush_events()
    n += 1
    print(n)

print('Exit with',n,'steps')
print(abba)
plt.show(block=True)
```

In your example changes happens at the very end of the loop.

Comment: Thank you for posting Mehdi - I tried you suggestion, but I still only get one picture on the screen.

Comment: You mean you can see the plot gets updated but in one figure/window? right?

Comment: Unfortunately, I only see one static picture - I do not see any updates, only the same picture.

Comment: terman, have you waited long enough? With your sample input, not much changes for some time, then suddenly everything happens in the last second. Start with 100 instead of 1000 and add `plt.pause(0.1)` at the end of the loop. Having said this, the matplotlib interactive mode is highly dependent on the operating system and IDE you use, information, we don't have.